# How to left-align elements in centered flexbox div?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm new to flexbox and trying to understand it. I'm trying to center a div that contains elements that wrap, but also left-align those elements inside of that.

I have a codepen here (https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GOWBxY), but all of the elements are centered!

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.container .card {
  padding: 20px 20px;
  margin: 1em;
  background: #ff6a6a;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  padding: 50px 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.cardTitle {
  height: 75%;
}

.card {
  min-height: 8em;
  width: 25%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1em #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="cardTitle">Hi</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="cardTitle">Hi</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="cardTitle">Hi</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="cardTitle">Hi</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="cardTitle">Hi</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just comment out: .container {justify-content: center;}

Answer (score 1):

`justify-content` is used for justifying its **child** elements, NOT the element itself.

So as @VXp already said, you can just comment out `justify-content: center`,  since the `justify-content: flex-start` is already a default value.

Also, If you want to center the `.container`,

1. Add `margin: 0 auto`
2. Or you can give `display: flex` and `justify-content: center` to the parent element which is `body` in your case.

Though your `.container` won't seem to be centered since its `width` value is 100%.

Comment: I tried your instructions, and it didn't center (https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xPqaRz). @jyoon